# cakephp $HttpSocket->request not returning a data

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi im trying to get some data to the main server and im using $HttpSocket->request. the problem is im not getting any data from it.

```
App::import('Core', 'HttpSocket');
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();
$request = array('auth' => array('username' =>'xxxx',
                                 'password' => 'xxxx',
                                'method' => 'Basic'),
                 'uri' => "http://test.com/xxxx/xxxx/{$xx}");
$result = $HttpSocket->request($request);

debug($HttpSocket->response);
debug($result);
```

any problem in this code?
any suggestion will be greatly appreciated thank you! Cheers!

Comment: What's the output of your debug statements? Are they completely empty?

Comment: And is your debug level set to 2? => Configure::write('debug', 2);

Comment: i used debug($HttpSocket->response) and it shows something like this [status-line] => HTTP/1.1 302 Found.. and other debug statement.. im new to cakephp $HttpSocket so i dont know how to handle this. thanks for your reply

Comment: If you're getting blank responses, make sure your Auth isn't blocking your request. ex: looking for "friends" via API: put this in appcontroller beforefilter. `$this->Auth->allow('friends');`